# Java get decimal byte representation of a character

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, ascii

I have the following code which prints out bytes from Strings `s0` and `s1`; the output results are commented:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String s0="H\u00ebllo";
    String s1="Hëllo";

    byte[] bytes=s0.getBytes("ISO8859_1"); //72 -21 108 108 111
    //byte[] bytes=s1.getBytes("ISO8859_1"); //72 -61 -85 108 108 111
    //byte[] bytes=s0.getBytes("UTF-8");  //72 -61 -85 108 108 111
    //byte[] bytes=s1.getBytes("UTF-8");  //72 -61 -125 -62 -85 108 108 111
    for (int i=0,  i<bytes.length; i++)  {
        System.out.println(bytes[i]);
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is where those numbers come from. Why are there negative numbers if all character codes are supposed to be positive? Why are there 6 numbers in the second case? Why are the numbers for the `ë` character different when using Unicode notation versus a literal?

**EDIT**:

I understood that those numbers come from first being converted to unsigned numbers:

`ë(ISO8859_1) = 0xeb = 235 = 11101011 = -21 (two's complement for signed numbers)`

`ë (UTF-8) = 0xc3 0xab => 0xc3 = 195 = 11000011 = -61, 0xab = 171 = 10101011 = -85`

But what I still don't get is the difference between the `s0` and `s1` strings.  In both cases, I ask for `ISO8859_1` bytes from `getBytes()`, while in the second case I still get `UTF-8`'s bytes.

**EDIT:**

And `byte[] bytes=s1.getBytes("UTF-8");` results in this output:

`72 -61 -125 -62 -85 108 108 111`

I'm really confused.

**EDIT**:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
System.out.println(java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset());
```

Both give `UTF-8`. Source file is in `UTF-8`.

Comment: What is the purpose of `k`?

Comment: @Andreas, It's part of a larger program, need `k` for personal reasons. Edited the post anyway.

Comment: Again, your source file is stored in UTF-8, so `ë` is stored as two bytes. Your compiler assumes a different encoding and misinterprets the UTF-8 `ë` as `Ã«` so when the code is executed it doesn't know anything about `Hëllo` but only knows `HÃ«llo` instead.

Comment: Strings in memory are encoded as UTF-16, not UTF-8. There is a translation between the file encoding and the in-memory encoding. You cannot get correct results reliably by looking at a `String` as a byte sequence. You have to see it as a `char` sequence. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5

Comment: @Markus Benko, But the IDEA says that my source file is run in UTF-8 (`-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`), does a compiler use a different encoding?

Comment: So you know and we know, what is the encoding that your source code editor uses to save the file and what are you telling your compiler it is?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1
"The Java programming language represents text in sequences of 16-bit code units, using the UTF-16 encoding."

Comment: A source file is not a string in memory.

Comment: @Tom Blodget, I know for sure that source file is in UTF-8 and is executed in UTF-8. I'm not sure where I should check the compiler's encoding, though, I think it's UTF-8 too.

Comment: `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` only affects what is considered the default charset when your Java program is run but not the encoding of your source file or which encoding your compiler expects.

Comment: If you don't tell the compiler which encoding the source file is, it'll probably have some default. I would just tell it. (`javac -help`, `javac -encoding…`)

Comment: @Tom Blodget, I edited the question. Looks like default is UTF-8 anyway.

Comment: What the runtime "default" character set doesn't matter (test JVM environment). It's how the source file is being read by the compiler that matters (Java build environment). I think what most [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42543214/2226988) (@MarkusBenko) are explaining is correct. I can reproduce your results if I compile a UTF-8 encoded source file with the lie to the compiler that its encoding is ISO8859-1. Whatever build system you are using is probably misconfigured.

Answer (score 3):

Bytes are signed numbers in Java and are in range -128 to 127. There are 6 numbers in the second case because your source file uses UTF-8 encoding and the Java compiler assumes a platform-specific encoding which is probably not UTF-8. When using an IDE look for settings corresponding to source and/or compiler encoding. When compiling using `javac` try specifying `-encoding UTF-8`.

Comment: But `ë` is Unicode's `U+00EB` and is `0xeb` in `ISO8859_1`. 0xeb is supposed to be 235 in decimal.

Comment: That `ë` in your source code as part of the string literal is stored as two bytes when using UTF-8. And no, *in Java* there doesn't exist any *byte* value that is supposed to be 235 in decimal.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, the `byte` primitive type is `signed`, which means that the range goes from -128 to +127 (the first bit is considered to be the sign of the number).

In extended ASCII and other 8-bit encodings, like ISO-8859-1, characters exist that have byte values greater than 127.  Those, will display as negative when printed as a standard Java `byte`.

If you are using UTF-8 (or another Unicode UTF encoding), non-ASCII characters are represented by 2-4 bytes, and again each one of them might be "greater than 127", so they will show up as negative as well when you simply print them as `byte` values.

Comment: Could you please explain how Java makes -21 (111101011) out of 0xeb=235 (011101011)? What is the rule utilized here? For all numbers greater than 127, make negative numbers out of them through 1-ing the first zero-bits?

Comment: @parsecer What you are looking for is a description of [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement), which is how most computers store signed integers.

Comment: @parsecer You will run into serious trouble sooner or later when your source file encoding is different from what your compiler expects. The last paragraph of this answer is incorrect, a String in Java has no relation to UTF-8 and `String.getBytes("ISO8859_1")` will never give you two bytes for one character.

Comment: The first bit is the signal. As it is flipped the rest is considered to be in 2's complement (flip all bits and add 1).  So 235 (11101011b) == 10000000b (signal) bit_OR 01101011b == 10000000b (signal) bit_OR NOT(0010100b + 1) == 10000000b (signal) bit_OR NOT(00010101b) == 10000000b (signal) bit_OR NOT(21) == -21

Answer (score 0):

In java, all numeric types are **signed** (as opposed to unsigned). Note that `char` is not a numeric type even though it can be used (abused) arithmetically.

Your encoding gives a `-21` which is just Java's `byte` representation of `0b11101011` or `0xEB`.

Comment: How come 235 becomes -21? After all, the first bit is zero which means it's a positive number. Having done the conversion 235->011101011 and reverse here http://www.exploringbinary.com/twos-complement-converter/, -21 never showed up...

Comment: This is because you have specified 9 bits because the site has shown you an error because 235 is out of range.

Comment: I edited the question, could please explain the difference between `s0` and `s1` cases?

Comment: `char` is a numeric type. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1

Comment: @LewBloch No. `For char, from '\u0000' to '\uffff' inclusive, that is, from 0 to 65535` - they specify code points, not numbers. The only reason Java interprets them as numbers is because they would otherwise receive the grudge of all c programmers who are used to stuff like `'a'<=c&&c<='z'` (something that is bad practice anyway because of stuff like e.g. [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC))

Comment: I'm going to stick with the Java Language Specification over your opinion on this one.